# Input button embedded in anchor tag not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, html

**DUPLICATE:** [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/my-links-dont-work-in-ie-but-do-in-firefox)

I have the following code that works in FF but not in IE, can anyone tell me why that would be?

```
<a href="ContentAdmin.aspx"><input type="button" value="Cancel" /></a>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want this code to do?  Click on the input, visit the href, or both?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/my-links-dont-work-in-ie-but-do-in-firefox

Comment: This is a much more descriptive title then the linked duplicate.