# Styling an anchor tag to look like a submit button

Tags: html, css

I have a form where there's a "Submit" button and a "Cancel" anchor.  The HTML is this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<a href="some_url">Cancel</a>
```

I'd like for the two to look and act the same.  Nothing fancy, just something similar to how the "Ask Question" anchor looks on StackOverflow.

I can get the two to look somewhat similar, with the bounding box, background color, and hover background color, but I can't quite get the height and vertical alignment to play nice with one another.  I'd post my CSS but it's such a mess at this point that I think it might be easier to just start from scratch, get a barebones CSS layout working, then move on from there.

P.S. I know I could use an  instead of an anchor and hook up the onClick event to do the redirect.  It's almost a matter of principle at this point now to get this right using an anchor (plus there are web spider considerations to take into consideration here).

Comment: *can't quite get the height and vertical alignment to play nice* how does it look like? How should it look like?

Comment: I'd just like them to look the same. The problem is that the anchor tag's height tends to not match up with the submit button's height in all browsers. Either that or they don't line up perfectly when placed side-by-side.

Comment: Just to be clear, both should look like the "Ask Question" button at the top-right corner of StackOverflow.  It's not exactly what I'm going for but it's close enough to use as a point of reference.

Comment: how possibly web spider considrations and principles force you not to use the same element if you want stuff to look the same?

Comment: @Hanan Because web spiders don't have javascript enabled so they'll never hit the Cancel page if I turn the anchor into a button.

Comment: why it matters they cant see your cancel?

Answer (score 48):

The best you can get with simple styles would be something like:

```
.likeabutton {
    text-decoration: none; font: menu;
    display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
    background: ButtonFace; color: ButtonText;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;
    border-color: ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight;
}
.likeabutton:active {
    border-color: ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow;
}
```

(Possibly with some kind of fix to stop IE6-IE7 treating focused buttons as being ‘active’.)

This won't necessarily look exactly like the buttons on the native desktop, though; indeed, for many desktop themes it won't be possible to reproduce the look of a button in simple CSS.

However, you can ask the browser to use native rendering, which is best of all:

```
.likeabutton {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none; font: menu; color: ButtonText;
    display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
}
```

Unfortunately, as you may have guessed from the browser-specific prefixes, this is a [CSS3 feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/) that isn't suppoorted everywhere yet. In particular IE and Opera will ignore it. But if you include the other styles as backup, the browsers that do support `appearance` drop that property, preferring the explicit backgrounds and borders!

What you might do is use the `appearance` styles as above by default, and do JavaScript fixups as necessary, eg.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var r= document.documentElement;
    if (!('appearance' in r || 'MozAppearance' in r || 'WebkitAppearance' in r)) {
        // add styles for background and border colours
        if (/* IE6 or IE7 */)
            // add mousedown, mouseup handlers to push the button in, if you can be bothered
        else
            // add styles for 'active' button
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The accepted answer is really a direct answer to the OP question. But this answer appears to be more practically usable.

Answer (score 21):

I hope this will help.

```
<a href="url"><button>SomeText</button></a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer

Comment: This isn't even valid HTML. How does it have 18 upvotes?

Comment: Works on my page in all popular browsers so I am happy with this straightforward simple solution. If it works its valid enough for my purposes.

Comment: @scriptz Even though it works, it is considered invalid HTML and sooner or later it may not work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I Suggest you to use both Input Submit / Button instead of anchor and put this line of code `onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';"`
 in that Input Submit / Button which you want to work as link.

**Submit Example**

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'some_url';" />
```

**Button Example**

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'some_url';" />Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS:

```
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4E9CAF;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

<a href="some_url" class="button ">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a button tag instead of the input, resetting it and put a span inside, you'll then just have to style both the link and the span in the same way.
It involve extra markup, but it worked for me.

the markup:

```
<button type="submit">
    <span>submit</span>
</button>
<a>cancel</a>
```

the css:

```
button[type="submit"] {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Links and inputs are very different things, used for very different purposes.  Looks to me like you need a *button* for the cancel:

```
<button>Cancel</button>
```

Or maybe an input:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to satisfy the original poster's question, but either of those worked for me, for a button to which I wanted to attach href="#target" for a bootstrap collapse toggle. (The attachment done with .NET codebehind, and needing to wire-up to numbered rows in a ListView)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a button and call the url with JavaScript?

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='url.html';return false;" />
```

Comment: Web spiders don't browse with javascript enabled, so they'll never hit the Cancel url.  I guess that's not a huge deal, I was just hoping there was a solution that would work with an anchor tag.

Comment: It's not the cleanest, but to put the spider consideration in, you could put a non-displayed link into place next to the button
<input /><a style="display:none;" href="url.html"></a>

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button"> HOME </a>
```

CSS

```
.button { 
         background-color: #00CCFF;
         padding: 8px 16px;
         display: inline-block;
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         border-radius: 3px;
}
.button:hover{ background-color: #0066FF;}
```

[Watch the tutorial](https://youtu.be/euti4HAJJfk)

https://youtu.be/euti4HAJJfk

Comment: This is a seven year old thread you are replying to and you do so poorly. What does your markup do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Style your change the Submit button to an anchor tag instead and submit using javascript:

```
<a class="link-button" href="javascript:submit();">Submit</a>
<a class="link-button" href="some_url">Cancel</a>

function submit() {
    var form = document.getElementById("form_id");
    form.submit();
}
```