# Make asp:linkbutton resemble asp:button

Tags: asp.net, button, linkbutton

Is it possible to change the style of an `asp:linkbutton` to make it exactly resemble an `asp:button`?

i.e.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a Button instead then?

Comment: @Anders: I should have anticipated that question. Long story. You don't want to know :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An asp:LinkButton is rendered as a simple HTML A tag, so you could easily style it into whatever you wanted using CSS.

See this for more info:

[Styling an anchor tag to look like a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button)

Comment: Thanks. That's the kind of thing. Just wondered if anyone had done this before.