# Passing selected item of DropDownList to ajaxy called action

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to pass the value of on of the selected item in the list to the action in ajaxy way:

View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ApplicationColumns", applicationColumns, new { @style = "width: 200px;" })%>
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("AddColumnToTrim", "AddColumnToTrim", new { columnName = ??? }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "columnsDiv" })%>
<div id="columnsDiv"></div>
```

I'm doing this cause I cannot post the whole form and just need to execute some logic depending on the chosen item and display it in partial view.
**How can I pass the value(or selected SelectListItem) of the selected item of the DropDownList to my action** please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a form would be the semantically correct way to do this:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddColumnToTrim", "SomeController", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "columnsDiv" })) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("ApplicationColumns", applicationColumns, new { @style = "width: 200px;" })%>
    <button type="submit">AddColumnToTrim</button>
<% } %>
```

Now the selected value of the dropdown will be automatically sent to the controller action using an AJAX call when this form is submitted:

```
public ActionResult AddColumnToTrim(string ApplicationColumns)
{
    ...
}
```

And, yes, you could [style this button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187796/29407) to look like an anchor.