# a href link that will act like a button

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, href

Is there any clean method to make a regular link :

```
<a href="[8]">Click here to read more...</a>
```

to act EXACTLY like a button

```
<button id="[8]">Click here to read more...</button>
```

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean 'act like a button'? What features do you want specifically?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: Take a look at the articles on that website :

http://puaction.com

Now... The 'Click here to read more...' is a button that looks like a link. I want to remove all the css gimicks and get it back to regular link <a> that will act like a button.

Comment: Niels Sønderbæk :: this is no duplicate I need the reverse method

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button?rq=1 CSS is going to be your only option as far as I'm aware

Comment: If you want it to be exactly like a `<button>`, then why don't you just use a `<button>`?

Comment: Have you considered just styling some text to look like a link and give it an onclick event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<a id="[8]" class="readmore" href="#">
    Click here to read more...
</a>
```

Adapting your javascript to the new "a":

```
$("a.readmore").click(function() { 
    var id=this.id.split('['); 
    var d_id=id[1].split(']'); 
    var ii=d_id[0] $('html, body').animate({ 
       scrollTop: $('[id='+ii+']').offset().top 
    }, 2000); 

    return false;
});
```

Just a tip, your string processing looks terrible, suggestion:

```
$("a.readmore").click(function() { 
    var id=this.id.match('[0-9]+');

    $('html, body').animate({ 
       scrollTop: $('[id='+ id +']').offset().top 
    }, 2000); 

    return false;
});
```

Ensure this code is being intercept by the page dom parser in the right time,
put it inside a

> $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Regards.

Comment: no I want to completely remove the button. I make the button looks like a link via css but this is not a clean method.

Comment: @masteringprojects can you use just an <a href=""></a> ??

Comment: @masteringprojects what do you mean by "with act exactly"? If you add on click return false it will not follow the href link. Therefore, it will behave like a button, assuming you added the appropriate CSS styles. Although, why do you need this, is it somekind of hack over an existing system?

Comment: no I have a function that split the [{number}] from the 

<button id="[8]">Click here to read more...</button>

and then it's open (slide to) article number 8 and so on...

Comment: This is the function :

$("button").click(function() {
    var id=this.id.split('[');
    var d_id=id[1].split(']')
    var ii=d_id[0]
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[id='+ii+']').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});

Comment: @masteringprojects switch the button to link then, like it is in my answer you code will work, just change the $("button") to $("a"), maybe consider add a class to "a" so you can write something more precise like $("a.readmore").

Comment: Yes it is working I have test in on jsfiddle working perfectly ! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/neWuc/

Thanks to João Pinho!

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH João Pinho ! Sorry that I can't vote up ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is good sir !
I hope this will satisfy your needs :).

```
<html>
<style>
    .lnkbtn{
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }

    .lnkbtn:hover{
        background-color: #aaa;
    }

    .lnkbtn:visited{
        color: blue;
    }

    .lnkbtn:active{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <a href = "http://www.google.com" class = "lnkbtn">Click me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That neither behaves nor looks like a button.

Comment: No, This is definetly NOT what I'm looking. I don't need the link to looks like a button I need the link to behave like a button.

Comment: Would you please describe "behave" ? What do you want an onclick event ? You could add an id to the link the and call it trough an external js file, like $("#btn").onclick = function(){ ... }