# scroll down in window browser

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js. What im trying here is to scroll down the browser window by clicking a button.
The Console gives me: `"window is not defined"`

I have this so far:

```
var widgets1 = require("sdk/widget");

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var widget1 = widgets1.Widget({
 id: "minus",
label: "slow",
contentURL: self.data.url("-.png"),
 onClick: function() {
 window.scrollTo(0,100);
}
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use anchors to do such a thing.

```
<a href="#anchor_name"><button>SomeText</button></a>

<a name="anchor_name"></a>
```

Based on : [Styling an anchor tag to look like a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button)