# HTML - How to place an anchor tag correctly?

Tags: html

What is the correct way to place an anchor tag? Is it inside or outside a button tag?

HTML

```
 <button>
    <a href="#"> CLICK </a>
 </button>


<a ref="#">
   <button> CLICK
   </button>
</a>
```

Comment: I would just use the link and style it!

Comment: None of them is good since they can both perform the same action. (buttons need javascript). Just use CSS to make the anchor look like a button.

Comment: Depends on your choice, but e.g bootstrap they created the acnhor tag outside the button tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. Anchors are forbidden from containing buttons and buttons are forbidden from containing anchors.

If you want a link, then use an anchor and [style it to look how you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187796/19068).

If you want a button (i.e. a control that does nothing other than trigger JavaScript) then use a button and style it to look how you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

HTML

```
<div style="margin:5px;">
   <a href="#" class="button">Click</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #AABBAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLk38ko8/)

Comment: Why is there a button element in HMTL5. Isn't it to structure the mark up?

Comment: @user2952265 See Quentin's answer!