# MVC Button click open in new Window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I need to open my view in a new window on this button click but it opens in the same window. This is the syntax I'm using.

```
<button  id="btnPrintReport" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("LoadReports", "DashBoard", new { target="_blank" })'" >Print</button>
```

Have I missed anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Try** `window.open` to open link in a new tab

```
onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("LoadReports", "DashBoard", new { target="_blank" })')"
```

**[DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open)**

Comment: I just want to open new tab when keyboard control button and mouse click is pressed
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sir this code always opens the window in new tab
My requirement is to open the tab when my control button is pressed along with mouse click.

Comment: in that case you have to put a condition above it for the same

Comment: The target URL parameter (target = "_blank") doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `<button>` won't work with `target`. Same goes for `input type="button" ... />` elements:

You need to use an anchor and style it with css as a button

```
<a href=@Url.Action("LoadReports", "DashBoard") id="aPrintReport" target="_blank" class="button">Print</a>

<!--taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button-->
.button {
    text-decoration: none; font: menu;
    display: inline-block; padding: 2px 8px;
    background: ButtonFace; color: ButtonText;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;
    border-color: ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight;
}
.button:active {
    border-color: ButtonShadow ButtonHighlight ButtonHighlight ButtonShadow;
}
```

Comment: Hi, What changes required to make the above if the action is post form action? AFAIK Url.Action is GET  only.