# CSS colors for footer button

Tags: html, css

Style every BUTTON in the FOOTER to have a white color

```css
footer {
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn-address">Address</button>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn-phone">phone</button>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn-birthday">Birthday</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please guys, i have limited hours left. helppp. i have included color:white; to my css footer class, still prompts its isnt correct. what should i please do?

Comment: Seems like you just want nesting. Css: `footer button { color: white; }`
Could you elaborate otherwise?

Comment: Please do not beg. We will answer if we understand the question

Comment: okay guys, here's the whole code

Comment: <style>
      
      footer {
        width: calc(100% - 2em);
        z-index: 500;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 1em;
      }
      
      H2{
        margin-bottom:100px
      }
      
      mdc-icon-button{
      } 
     
      material-icons{
      }
      
      
      
     
     
      
    </style>

Comment: Please update the snippet instead of posting code in a comment!!. Also include `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want colored white. The button's background? The button's label? The icons inside the buttons? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer {
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

footer button{
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff0000;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn- 
          address">Address</button>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn- 
          phone">phone</button>
  <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" id="btn- 
          birthday">Birthday</button>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your **style tag**

```
footer button{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: still hasn't worked. https://alc-dev-toolkit-d50fe.firebaseapp.com/Um1nGA4YQscSdwYHQjQB/!#playground

Comment: your whole footer tag is not parsing by the browser. You can check the inspect element feature.

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS Class

```
.button {
display: block;
width: 115px;
height: 25px;
background: #4E9CAF;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and include class for the Buttons inside < footer > tag

For more Info Trying Reading 
[Styling an anchor tag to look like a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187008/styling-an-anchor-tag-to-look-like-a-submit-button)

Comment: all of these answers are correct. but i do not know what plugin Andela uses. the buttons have all changed to white but i can't pass this present stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer button {
    background-color: white
}
```

`color` will define the color of the text in the button, but it sounds like you want the button itself to be white.