# compatibility with button tag with achor tag in it with Chrome Firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, button, cross-browser, anchor

I have the following code

```
<button><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></button>
```

What i am doing that, if user click on the button, link to logout where session is terminated and redirected to login page. Scenario is that when i work on it, everything go fine in Chrome while Firefox and IE doesn't have any effect on click of button tag. Any suggestion for making the code browser compatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

A `<button>` tag is not designed to have an `<a>` tag inside it. As you've found, it doesn't work, and it isn't really logical either. A button is designed to accept a click event to be handled by Javascript on the same page, whereas a link takes a click event and directs it to a new page -- put one inside the other and the two actions are in conflict with each other.

If you want to have a link that looks like a button, you should style it to look like a button, rather than trying to wrap a button around it just for the visual effect.

Comment: Thanks i am committing same mistake again but why this work in chrome?