# Links working in Chrome but not in IE?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, href

So I just built a new page and the links work in Chrome AND IE 10 on my local machine but when I upload the site to my server the links only work in chrome? IE acts like there is nothing there?

This is the code behind and here is the link if you want to try it yourself. I haven't even tried Firefox yet. I am afraid what that will do.

http://www.AnthonyRussell.info

Thanks in advance!

```
    <hr>
    <a href="index.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px" >Home</button></a>
    <a href="bio.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px">Biography</button></a>
    <a href="projects.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px">Projects</button></a>
    <a href="resume.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px">Abv Resume</button></a>
    <a href="goals.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px">Goals</button></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><button style="width:180px; height:40px">Contact</button></a>
    <hr>
```

Comment: Could it be a problem on my local machine then with IE?

Comment: Could it be a problem with IE10? Is that what you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `<button>` inside an `<a>` tag. What is it you're trying to do to need a button element?

Update:

For more information and possible workaround try:

[Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802839/1306351)

But I'd say styling your own CSS buttons would be better. Try http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ if you're short on time.

Comment: I just wanted a different look to my site and didn't want to make my own button so I used them as navigation links lol

Comment: Also you can have a <Button> inside an <a> obviously because it is working everywhere but on my local machine apparently

Comment: It's 'allowed' yes (as far as I know). But some versions of IE don't support it. If you want to run that risk then that's up to you.

Comment: see my updated answer for some more on the topic and CSS button generator.

Comment: I just tried that and it still isn't working.

Comment: Got it working. It was my mistake with syntactical error. First answer works best.