# HTML a href link with button not work in firefox but work google chrome why is it?

Tags: html

Why this html code not work in **firefox** ? when i clicked the button link not work but **google** chrome work fine.

```
<button>
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="index.php?cmd=BlogAddForm">Add Note</a>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML. Some browsers allow it, others don't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Oops, just realized that duplicate question is the opposite nesting. But they're both invalid.

Comment: It works for me on FF 25.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not valid: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html - an `<a>` element is an "interactive element", which is not allowed: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content says Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.

--> a (if it contains only phrasing content)

Comment: And `<a>` could be phrasing content when it only contains phrasing content?

Comment: @Banana-In-Black An `<a>` element with an `href` attribute is an interactive element. It can still have phrasing content, but it can't be nested within a `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically not valid html syntax.  Some browsers allow it, but you would need to remove the anchor tag from within the button.