# button not redirecting to spring controller

Tags: spring, jstl

I have a anchor tag enclosing a button I want to redirect it to spring controller when click the button. The below code is working on chrome browser but it is not working in IE. could you please help me?

```
<spring:url value="/auth/userhome" var="homepage" />
        <a href="${homepage}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary cancel">
                <spring:message code="button.cancel" />
            </button> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this thread: [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

That will fix your problem:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';"/>
```