# <a> tag issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I have used `<a>` tag inside `<div>` which is not working in IE

my code structure is like :

```
<div>
    <a target="_top" href="address">
       <button>
       </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

So It is working fine in all browsers except IE.
When I click on button it is not redirected to specified url from  tag.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please provide us some code so we can help you out.

Comment: and what is `address`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is not recommended - don't wrap a button in a link. Style your link like a button or use an onclick:

```
<button onclick="window.open(href);">
</button>
```

(Addendum: Just for accessibility, don't use target on your links since it messes with people who use screen readers. Only apply a target after page load when there is javascript available. Also, people like to control where their new page opens - it's not something you should try to dictate too much.)

Comment: I have used iframe, so I need to use <a> tag for Target to Redirect. And this code nicely working in all browsers.

Comment: Then style your link as a button.

Answer (score 1):

`button` tag is only allowed within a `<form>` tag. Since there is no form, IE is ignoring this. Other browser have a more defensive "do what I mean" parser probably ...

You might do it like this:

```
 <input type="button" onClick="document.location='address'; return false" value="click me" />
```

Comment: I completely forgot the form tag issue of IE. Good to keep in mind.