# Button not working on IE11 browser but work on others

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla3.0

The site is running on Joomla + Seblod CCK. The HTML buttons (Post Individual and Post Company) won’t work on Internet Explorer browser. [See URL Here](http://www.searchfirst.ng/index.php)
I tested this on both Windows 8.1 and 10, and neither worked. However, this same buttons work fine on other browsers.

Here goes the minimal HTML/Bootstrap code:

```
<center><p><a href="index.php/individual-form">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive" type="button">Post Individual</button></a><a href="index.php/company-form">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive" type="button">Post Company</button></a></p></center>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link it was helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score -1):

The post on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer) helped.

Since I got bootstrap on the site, the code below did the magic

```
<a href="link.com" class="btn" >Checkout</a>
```

Thanks