# How can I use button to add link in ie8?

Tags: html, url, button, hyperlink

I using this code in IE8:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button>google</button></a>
```

When I run it button will appear but when I click the button the URL I put is not why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button inside of anchor link works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802839/button-inside-of-anchor-link-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-internet-explorer)